Sudenly Error "Already Initialized" when invoke Mint New Edition from Master Edition Via Token in cpi mpl token metadata
im try to create nft with print from master edition, previously my contract its working for 3months, but now I often encounter this error sudenly, this error say "Already initialized" when invoke "Mint New Edition from Master Edition Via Token" from mpl token metadata. are u guys have experiences like whats wrong or any idea for this error? thanks.

This My Main Intrusction Code :
// step: mint
// create account mint address
msg!("create mint account");
system_program::create_account(
    CpiContext::new(
        ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
        system_program::CreateAccount {
            from: user.to_account_info(),
            to: new_mint.to_account_info()
        },
    ),
    10000000,
    82,
    &ctx.accounts.token_program.key(),
)?;

// Initialize mint account
msg!("Initializing mint account");
anchor_spl::token::initialize_mint(
    CpiContext::new(
        ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
        anchor_spl::token::InitializeMint {
            mint: new_mint.to_account_info(),
            rent: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
        },
    ),
    0,
    &ctx.accounts.user.key(),
    Some(&ctx.accounts.user.key()),
)?;

// associate token account
msg!("Creating associated token account");
anchor_spl::associated_token::create(
    CpiContext::new(
        ctx.accounts.associated_token_program.to_account_info(),
        anchor_spl::associated_token::Create {
            payer: user.to_account_info(),
            associated_token: new_token.to_account_info(),
            authority: user.to_account_info(),
            mint: new_mint.to_account_info(),
            system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            token_program: ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
        },
    ),
)?;

// Mint to token account
msg!("Minting to token account");
anchor_spl::token::mint_to(
    CpiContext::new(
        ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
        anchor_spl::token::MintTo {
            mint: new_mint.to_account_info(),
            to: new_token.to_account_info(),
            authority: user.to_account_info(),
        },
    ),
    1,
)?;

spl_token_metadata_mint_new_edition_from_master_edition_via_token(
    &new_metadata.to_account_info(),
    &new_edition.to_account_info(),
    &new_mint.to_account_info(),
    &user.to_account_info(),
    &user.to_account_info(),

    &ctx.accounts.authority.to_account_info(),
    &update_authority.to_account_info(), // before is user

    &token.to_account_info(),
    &metadata.to_account_info(),
    &edition.to_account_info(),
    &mint.to_account_info(),
    &edition_mark.to_account_info(),
    &ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
    &ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
    &ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
    &edition.supply + 1,
    &[
        <MY_SIGNER_SEED>
    ],
)?;

And this for my utils :
#[allow(clippy::too_many_arguments)]
pub fn spl_token_metadata_mint_new_edition_from_master_edition_via_token<'a>(
    new_metadata_account: &AccountInfo<'a>,
    new_edition_account: &AccountInfo<'a>,
    new_mint_account: &AccountInfo<'a>,
    new_mint_authority_account: &AccountInfo<'a>,
    user_wallet_account: &AccountInfo<'a>,
    program_authority_account: &AccountInfo<'a>,
    update_authority_account: &AccountInfo<'a>,
    user_token_account: &AccountInfo<'a>,
    master_metadata_account: &AccountInfo<'a>,
    master_edition_account: &AccountInfo<'a>,
    master_metadata_mint_account: &AccountInfo<'a>,
    edition_mark_account: &AccountInfo<'a>,
    token_program_account: &AccountInfo<'a>,
    system_program_account: &AccountInfo<'a>,
    rent_program_account: &AccountInfo<'a>,
    edition: u64,
    signers_seeds: &[&[u8]],
) -> Result<()> {
    let tx = mpl_token_metadata::instruction::mint_new_edition_from_master_edition_via_token(
        mpl_token_metadata::id(),
        *new_metadata_account.key,
        *new_edition_account.key,
        *master_edition_account.key,
        *new_mint_account.key,
        *new_mint_authority_account.key,
        *user_wallet_account.key,
        *program_authority_account.key,
        *user_token_account.key,
        *update_authority_account.key,
        *master_metadata_account.key,
        *master_metadata_mint_account.key,
        edition,
    );

    invoke_signed(
        &tx,
        &[
            new_metadata_account.clone(),
            new_edition_account.clone(),
            master_edition_account.clone(),
            new_mint_account.clone(),
            edition_mark_account.clone(),
            new_mint_authority_account.clone(),
            user_wallet_account.clone(),
            program_authority_account.clone(),
            user_token_account.clone(),
            update_authority_account.clone(),
            master_metadata_account.clone(),
            token_program_account.clone(),
            system_program_account.clone(),
            rent_program_account.clone(),
        ],
        &[&signers_seeds],
    )?;

    Ok(())
}

